# How to Send IOCTL's to all drivers on windows in C

Tags: c, windows, driver

Can someone provide me with a sample C code that list´s all device Names that i can open with Createfile()? i always get error code 3 : path does not exist

sample code that doesnt works:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <regstr.h>
#include <devioctl.h>
#include <usb.h>
#include <usbiodef.h>
#include <usbioctl.h>
#include <usbprint.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <wdmguid.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Setupapi.lib")
int main(void){
    HDEVINFO deviceInfoList;
    deviceInfoList = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DIGCF_PRESENT);

    if (deviceInfoList != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;
        deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
        for (DWORD i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoList, i, &deviceInfoData); i++)
        {
            LPTSTR buffer = NULL;
            DWORD buffersize = 0;
            while (!SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceIdA(deviceInfoList, &deviceInfoData, buffer, buffersize, &buffersize))
            {
                if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
                {
                    if (buffer) delete buffer;
                    buffer = new TCHAR[buffersize];
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%ls\n", "error");
                    break;
                }
            }
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(buffer,
                GENERIC_READ,
                0,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                NULL);

            if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                printf("InvalidHandle, error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
            }
            CloseHandle(hFile);

            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            if (buffer) { delete buffer; buffer = NULL; }
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

my Goal is to print all valid device Names and try to get a valid handle on it that i can later user for sending ioctl`s

thx

EDIT:
ok abhineet so thats what i got now :

```
DWORD EnumerateDevices(){
    DWORD dwResult = 0;

    HDEVINFO hdev = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_BATTERY, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);// DIGCF_ALLCLASSES
    /*HDEVINFO hdev =SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,
        0, // Enumerator
        0,
        DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES); */
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hdev) {
        for (int idev = 0; idev < 100; idev++)
        {
            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA did = { 0 };
            did.cbSize = sizeof(did);

            if (SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hdev, NULL, &GUID_DEVCLASS_BATTERY, idev, &did))
            {
                DWORD cbRequired = 0;

                SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdev,
                    &did,
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    &cbRequired,
                    0);
                if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == GetLastError())
                {
                    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pdidd = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)LocalAlloc(LPTR, cbRequired);
                    if (pdidd) {
                        pdidd->cbSize = sizeof(*pdidd);
                        if (SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hdev, &did, pdidd, cbRequired, &cbRequired, 0)) {
                            wprintf(L"%s\n", pdidd->DevicePath);
                            HANDLE hBattery = CreateFile(pdidd->DevicePath,
                                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                NULL,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                NULL);
                            if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hBattery)
                            {
                                printf("Successfully opened Handle\n");
                                CloseHandle(hBattery);
                            }
                            else{
                                wprintf(L"CreateFile(%s) failed %d\n", pdidd->DevicePath, GetLastError());
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() failed %d\n", GetLastError());
                        }
                        LocalFree(pdidd);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail() failed %d\n", GetLastError());
                }
            }
            else  if (ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS == GetLastError())
            {
                printf("-NoMoreItems-");
                break;  // Enumeration failed - perhaps we're out of items
            }
        }
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hdev);
    }
    else{
        printf("SetupDiGetClassDevs() failed %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return dwResult;
}
```

i ripped the most from here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204769(v=vs.85).aspx

and my Output is :

```
\\?\acpi#pnp0c0a#1#{72631e54-78a4-11d0-bcf7-00aa00b7b32a}
Successfully opened Handle
-NoMoreItems-
```

at least i got a valid handle!
**so i wanna do this an all devices avaible on the System , how to do that?**

Comment: Well, you could repeat the same process for each device class.  There may be an easier way; try passing `NULL` instead of a class GUID, for example.  But really there wouldn't be any point; if you don't (at a minimum) know the device class, how would you know what IOCTLs are valid?

Comment: @harry johnston 1. already done that but then i just get -NoMoreItems- 2. brute-force, reverse Engineering . My Goal is just to send an ioctl to every .sys Driver-Service that is currently running.

Comment: and btw: you cant pass NULL as ClassGuid to SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces , you get AV reading at 0x0

Comment: When you run out of items in one device class, you start again with the next device class.

Comment: i tryed so many ClassGuid´s and almost all of them except the battery class ONLY Returns -NoMoreItems-, so do i Need to hardcode every classguid function call ? there are so many ...

Comment: Have you tried a class for which you know a device interface exists, e.g., GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK?

Comment: just tried it , i got 2 handles running as admin. But i want to get handles to all running .sys Services running on my System. thx for you help

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I don't think, you can do a `CreateFile` on `InstanceID`. To do a `CreateFile`, you need the symbolic name of the device. You can use the following SetupAPIs,

- [SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551015(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120(v=vs.85).aspx)

The **Remark** section of both APIs state that,

> **SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces::** DeviceInterfaceData points to a structure that identifies a requested
>   device interface. To get detailed information about an interface, call
>   SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail. ***The detailed information includes the
>   name of the device interface that can be passed to a Win32 function
>   such as CreateFile*** (described in Microsoft Windows SDK documentation)
>   to get a handle to the interface.
>
> **SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail::** ***The interface detail returned by this function consists of a device path that can be passed to Win32
>   functions such as CreateFile.*** Do not attempt to parse the device path
>   symbolic name. The device path can be reused across system starts.

This might be of your use, [how to get DevicePath from DeviceID](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/23aed79d-c023-4668-a606-f2160b318498/how-to-get-devicepath-from-deviceid?forum=windowssdk)